# Effects of leaving Track Changes on when accepting or rejecting changes? (Word for PC)

Tags: microsoft-word, editing

I used track changes to accept or reject edits that I made to my own document.

The next day I continued my work (accepting/rejecting changes) and discovered that edits that I thought I had finalized were not, in fact, permanent.

I don't use track changes very often and (shame on me) I was not paying particular attention to whether track changes was on or off while I was accepting or rejecting the edits.

If it was, in fact, ON then was I sending Word into some kind of recursive loop where that kept my changes from sticking?

If On/Off is irrelevant, then what can I do in the future to prevent the situation?

Note: Before asking this question, I tried googling and binging for an answer by using variations of the subject line for this post.

Comment: Which view are you currently in? Final or Final with Markup?

Comment: Ah, well, I closed the file shortly after posting my question. But I would say that my view was Final with Markup (because that's the only way you can see what to accept or reject).

Answer (score 1):

I use Track Changes a lot in Word 2010 (and previously in 2007), and I usually leave tracked changes on when accepting changes. The only problem I've had is that if there are a lot of changes and comments, Word will sometimes skip some the first time through. Usually it only does that with paragraph formatting. I don't know if this is changed in Word 2013 or Office 365, though.

Are you editing your changes as you review them? If so, Word will start looking *after* the change you just made unless you move the caret back before it.

Comment: I do often edit-my-edits. I gave this answer an upvote because of its reminder to pay attention to whether I want to continue forward in my document or to move backward.